# Как не написать троян, если я не пишу троян?

Tags: c#, winforms

Учу винформы. Сделал простое приложение и скинул другу. Его ОС ругается, что моя программа - троян вин 32. Вопрос простой - как и что сделать (если реально), чтобы я мог в будущем тестировать свои программы на чужих ПК?

ОС – windows 10, ругается фаервол.

Comment: Уточните, что именно делает ваше приложение. Я почти уверен, что оно пишет в файлы в папке, где само расположено.

Comment: Просто воспроизводит wav из своих же ресурсов

Comment: Эвристические сканеры антивирусов часто ругаются на любые подозрительные действия от программ без цифровой подписи (например, скачивание файлов по заранее прошитому в коде URL, изменение файлов в Program Files и т.п.)

Comment: @Генрих, вы под словом "пекарня" имеете ввиду аббревиатуру ПК?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, например, у меня просто вводиться данные с клавиатуры и обычный вывод. Но у других тоже постоянно вылазит это предупреждение.. *К заметке, я пишу на С++ консольные программы.*

Comment: Кстати обошел данную проблему путем компиляции приложения на стороне Microsoft, запаковкой приложения в zip архив и распространение через сайт с SSL сертификатом (HTTPS), вроде не один антивирус после такого ложно на мое детище не ругался)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ с отправкой тоже танцевал под бой в бубны - в вк не грузился даже в архиве, gmail просто блокировал отправку. пришлось кинуть в архив и "сломать" расширение (.rar => .r), таки получилось перекинуть в вк, но когда друг дописал расширение и попробовал извлечь - файл заблокировался.

Comment: @Генрих, а вы видели ли уже [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769043/Писал-код-получился-троян)? Просто любопытно, а не используется ли у вас в коде аналогичная функция - показывать свое окно поверх всех остальных?

Comment: @Uranus, не видел. сразу скажу - ничего подобного в коде нет. вся "программа" - это винформа с фоткой на бэкграунд и единственной кнопкой, при нажатии которой воспроизводится wav из ресурсов. больше там ВООБЩЕ ничего нет, так что единственное, на что кашляю - отсутствие цифровой подписи (хотя я пока даже не знаю, как и в каком окне регистратуры ее получать), иначе какие варианты?

Answer (score 7):

Windows Firewall обычно ругается на попытки открыть TCP порт. Это не является признаком трояна, и многие программы используют такую возможность Windows. Например, при конфигурировании SQL сервер необходимо добавлять исключение в Firewall если нужно чтобы сервер был доступен другим компьютерам. Таким образом, если приложению необходимо работать с сетевыми ресурсами, можно проинструктировать пользователей как настроить исключения в Windows Firewall.

Возможно, существуют так же решения для автоматической настройки исключений во время установки программы. Я таких не знаю, возможно кто нибудь другой добавит еще один ответ.

Так же существуют случаи блокировки программы антивирусами. С подобными проблемами иногда сталкиваются даже разработчики реальных продуктов, а не только HelloWorld приложений. Мне известны только два способа решения проблемы:

1. Убедить пользователей добавить исключение для своего приложение, если это приложение уровня небольшой утилиты для узкого круга.
2. Обратиться в техподдержку антивируса, и четко описать проблему. То, что приложение определяется как троян, это в первую очередь баг антивируса, и с большой долей вероятности его исправят.

Кстати, не всегда общение с техподдержкой проходит гладко. Иногда бывает так, как написано в этой статье на хабре: [Программист и антивирус](https://habrahabr.ru/post/77587/)

Comment: Друг говорит, что ругается непосредственно виндовый фаервол, так что не знаю, получится ли связаться с майками по этому поводу, хотя почему бы и нет. как проснется - попрошу у него скрин, чтоб уж точно знать. просто если я напишу уже что-то рабочее, то в идеале нужно будет потестить на чужих машинах, а никак))

Comment: Эта новая информация,  т.к. жаргонизм "пекарня" не является общепринятым обозначением для windows firewall или windows defender. Исправьте, пожалуйста, свой вопрос, или задайте новый, чтобы получить более правильные ответы.

Comment: спасибо, учтем, будем использовать

Comment: @Uranus, боюсь "пекарня" - это не windows firewall или windows defender ;)

Comment: @Генрих, спасибо. Я обновил ответ, чтобы он соответствовал вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

РЕШЕНО. Проблема была в том, что я не указал разрядность архитектуры для сборки, то есть у меня вместо х84/х64 стояло "Any CPU". Не знаю с чем это связано, но поставив на х84 (у меня VS2010, х64 - нет в выборе) - проблема исчезла, прога успешно запустилась на чужом компьютере.