# При установке свойства TopMost приложение воспринимается как троян

Tags: c#, winforms

Писал Winform-приложение, чтобы делать скриншоты выбранной области экрана (аналог "Ножниц" от Windows).

Для свойства `TopMost` одной из форм приложения присвоил `true`, чтобы окно с захваченным экраном было поверх остальных. В итоге после проверки антивирусом (Windows Defender) получил Trojan:Win32/Fuerboos.A!cl. Устанавливал `false`, тестировал - антивирус ничего не находил. Приложение никак не взаимодействует с какими-либо сетевыми портами. Цифровая подпись присутствует.

Вот часть кода этой формы ([здесь класс полностью](https://pastebin.com/U0qD9FtA)):

```
public Image Image { get; set; }

public Rectangle RectangleSelect
{
    set
    {
        rectangleSelect = new Rectangle();
    }
}

public static Image Snip()
{
    var rectangle = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb))
    {
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);

        using (var snipper = new SnippingTool(bitmap))
        {
            if (snipper.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return snipper.Image;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public SnippingTool(Bitmap screenShot)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BackgroundImage = screenShot;
    this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
}
```

Как можно исправить проблему?
P.S. Virustotal вообще не находит ничего.
P.P.S Написал в twitter MS Defender, жду ответа.

---

**EDIT #0**: Создал пустой проект с пустой формой, присвоил ей `TopMost` `true` - в результате тот же вирус.
**EDIT #1**: по совету [MSDN.WhiteKnight](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/240512/msdn-whiteknight) создал checkbox, установил ему `Ckecked=true, Visible=false`, на этом основании устанавливал `TopMost=true`, это не помогло. Перенес checkbox в другую форму, тоже не помогло.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как не написать троян, если я не пишу троян?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768623/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%88%d1%83-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ нет, не дубликат. Ответы, данные на указанный вами вопрос никак не сопоставимы с моим. Просьба читать вопросы полностью.

Comment: Не используйте антивирусы (хороший комментарий)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, есть такое предчувствие, что это как раз автору того вопроса надо будет дать ссылку на этот, если тут кто-нибудь даст решение. В том вопросе очень туманно описана проблема, но возможно что она как раз  аналогична описанной тут. Только мой ответ явно не подходит.

Comment: открытие поверх других окон - типичное поведение блокировщиков, вероятно на это и агрится антивирус, только все остальное не проверяет и выдает ложное срабатывание. Единственный адекватный вариант - трясти поддержку MS. Или ждать очередного обновления Defender-а. Касперский, например,  не так давно агрился на подпику на события контролов лябдой, вместо отдельного метода.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я уточнил у автора того вопроса в комментариях, он подтвердил что у него проблема не связана с обсуждаемой здесь.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Не нужно закрывать вопрос дубликатом. Этот вопрос о конкретной проблеме, а тот слишком общий, и ответы соответственные.

Comment: Не могу воспроизвести. Копирую код в проект, добавляю конструктор без параметров для формы, собираю, проверяю Defender'ом - ничего не находит. Или чтобы это воспроизвести, нужно обязательно проверять не на том компе, на котором собирал?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight обновился до базы 11 января - вирусов не обнаружено. Даже не знаю, закрывать ли вопрос...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71551/discussion-on-question-by-tarasovych----topmost--).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хоть проблема была решена [обновлением определений вирусов до последней версии](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42225209#42225209) наверное, имеет смысл что-то написать для истории.

[Win32/Fuerboos](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description?Name=Trojan:Win32/Fuerboos.A!cl) - это эвристическое правило в Windows Defender, которое может определять различные типы вредоносных программ. **Эвристическое правило** - это правило, которое использует некий набор характерных признаков для выявления в том числе неизвестных вирусов, в противоположность **сигнатурному** анализу, выполняющему сравнение последовательности байтов с уже известными сигнатурами вирусов. Таким признаком может быть, например, скачивание файла по заранее прошитому в коде URL - признак трояна / клиента ботнета, скачивающего свой конфиг.

На приложения без цифровой подписи, или с бессмысленным именем издателя типа "Неизвестный издатель" в свойствах сборки, эвристические правила срабатывают чаще. Поэтому, при распространении программ желательно позаботиться об этих аспектах.

Установка свойства `TopMost` тоже может таким признаком, особенно для окна большого размера: это может быть расценено как попытка скрыть часть экрана от пользователя и помешать его работе. Хорошо, что MS в обновлении уменьшили роль этого фактора, но все же рекомендуется не злоупотреблять размещением своего окна поверх всех окон (обязательно сделать возможность это отключить).

Comment: Отметил как ответ! Спасибо! P. S. Решил добавить опцию запуска приложения вместе с Windows - Trojan:Win32/Spursint.F!cl теперь. Уж буду смотреть, видимо с реестром что-то не так сделал, хотя руководствовался ответом [отсюда](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/19d36075-3256-46e5-8a76-9a9c435f4d39/make-program-run-on-startup-via-installer?forum=csharpgeneral). Думаю проблема в саморобной подписи приложения еще.