# Ребят что делать дефендер считает мою программу вирусом?

Tags: c#, defender

Написал приложение клиент для соц сети на C# и дефендер считает его вирусом что за беспредел? Trojan:Win32/Sprisky.W!cl

Comment: Пишите в Микрософт.

Comment: @Василий Кристов http://holdemmanager.nlclub.org/faq/275.html

Comment: Ну дефендер как бы не брал на себя обязательств считать твою программу чистой. Вероятно, у тебя есть в программе некий блок кода, (возможно, случайно) соответствующий сигнатуре указанного трояна - а разбираться досконально ему недосуг.

Comment: Хотелось бы знать какая у Вас сборка x86/x64, или Any CPU ? если указано любая разрядность смените её на конкретную x86, или x64 поведение антивируса сменится.

Comment: Программа подписана цифровой подписью? Установлена через 
подписанный инсталлятор? Что говорит [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com)? Посмотри в [RSDN.Shareware](http://rsdn.org/?forum/shareware/),  там много говориться о таких случаях.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uL6vFYLX7Bk (Простите, не удержался.)

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768623/Как-не-написать-троян-если-я-не-пишу-троян?noredirect=1&lq=1 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769043/При-установке-свойства-topmost-приложение-воспринимается-как-троян

Comment: @MaLS, если он сам написал программу, то на оба первых вопроса ответ "нет".

Comment: Сам написал. Отписал в майкрософт. Они сказали что это от обфуксации. В ближайшее время исправят при обновлении баз. Идиотизм какой то

Comment: @Qwertiy Не логично. Я тоже сам программы пишу, но при этом делаю для них инсталляторы и пописываю их подписью Code Signinger. Антивирусы не ругаються. Правда, я никогда не делаю обфускации. Не вижу в этом смысла.

Answer (score 2):

Комментарии пока не могу писать, поэтому в виде ответа:

> +1 Пишите в Микрософт. – Владимир Мартьянов

С темой **false positive**.
Проверься на **Virustotal** и в письме обязательно дай **ссылку на репорт**.
Если он, конечно, обнадеживающий :)
.

Comment: У него ж исходник есть - это его программа.

Comment: `У него ж исходник есть - это его программа.` - интересно сколько .dll на с++ да ещё и под протектором :-)

Comment: Дык... кто мешает откомпилить и скормить Вирустоталу? Хоть длл-кой, хоть екзешником, хоть тушкой, хоть чучелком :) Важно получить аргумент для БГ, или же наоборот, если все движки орать будут, - смотреть ,что, где и почему :( ...

Comment: @user6698332 Вирустотал говорит все отлично

Comment: @ВасилийКристов, отлично. Искренне рад за тебя. Будет весомым аргументом для БГ. Жаль, что ссылку не дал - я чой-то не помню - есть ли у Тотала в обойме Дефендер?